# VPS with Centos 6 Apache server and Directadmin - something is using all the arm

Tags: linux, memory, apache-http-server, centos

I'm using Direct Admin on Centos 6 on a VPS that has 32 GB RAM which has 2 WordPress websites

yesterday, I opened my site and it was super slow
I opened the Apache's server status and I didn't see anything weird
I used free -g command and saw that 32 GB of my ram been use and 0 free
I used Direct Admin service monitor to see which service is using all that RAM but the most usage service is the anti-virus (clamd) witch is using 771 MB.
after that httpd with 480 MB and nothing is even close to use half of the RAM

I used top command and that shows me something very similar
When I reboot the server it's fixed for a while but after 3-4 minutes it comes back

I'm using that VPS over a year now and that's the first time it happens
all the domains that point to the server are working though Cloudsflare and I've checked the brute force monitor but nothing weird there

How can I know who is using all the ram and how can I kill it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the problem keeps coming back, it sounds like a malicious script, how you identify a malicious script is not within scope (IMO).

Comment: for stuff like this the -g flag is not helpful at all, just use "free" without options for a more precise number.
you have 29GB in cache, use " slabtop -s c " to see the largest things in cache.

Comment: slabtop -s c returns No such file or directory